# C - creating a menu with gtk3

Tags: c, menu, gtk3

I'm trying to make a simple menu in gtk3. I was looking at the official documentation and other code I found in the web, but still I am not able to get it to work. The menu does not appear.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include "minefield.h"

enum difficulty {BEGINNER, ADVANCED, EXPERT};

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data);
GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf(const gchar * filename);

void newGame();
void openSetupDialog();
void openOptionDialog();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("my.ne.sweeper", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GdkPixbuf *app_icon;
    GtkWidget *app_window;
    GtkWidget *app_box;
    GtkWidget *menubar;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu_game;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu_newGame;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu_setup;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu_options;
    GtkWidget *gameMenu_quit;
    GtkWidget *sep;

    // App_window
    app_window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(app_window), "Minesweeper");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(app_window), 600, 400);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(app_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    // App_box
    app_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(app_window), app_box);
    // App_icon
    app_icon = create_pixbuf("../img/app_icon.svg");
    gtk_window_set_icon(GTK_WINDOW(app_window), app_icon);

    // Menubar
    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(app_box), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    // Start menu
    gameMenu = gtk_menu_new();
    gameMenu_game = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Game");
    gameMenu_newGame = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("New Game");
    gameMenu_setup = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Setup");
    gameMenu_options = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Options");
    gameMenu_quit = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");
    sep = gtk_separator_menu_item_new();

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(gameMenu_game), gameMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), gameMenu_game);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(gameMenu), gameMenu_newGame);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(gameMenu), gameMenu_setup);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(gameMenu), gameMenu_options);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(gameMenu), sep);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(gameMenu), gameMenu_quit);

    gtk_widget_show_all(app_window);

    // Signalhandlers
    g_signal_connect(app_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(gameMenu_newGame, "activate", G_CALLBACK(newGame), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(gameMenu_setup, "activate", G_CALLBACK(openSetupDialog), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(gameMenu_options, "activate", G_CALLBACK(openOptionDialog), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(gameMenu_quit, "activate", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_object_unref(app_icon);
}

GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf(const gchar * filename) {

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError *error = NULL;
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(filename, &error);

    if (!pixbuf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[!] %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
    }

    return pixbuf;
}

void newGame() {
    fprintf(stdout, "[*] %s\n", "new game..");
}

void openSetupDialog() {
    fprintf(stdout, "[*] %s\n", "open setup..");
}

void openOptionDialog() {
    fprintf(stdout, "[*] %s\n", "open options..");
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem that you have stated, and the menu does show and work for me. You do have other issues with your code which involves initialising and exiting GTK+.

Comment: @Errolvandel'Isle Ok, I dont know why, but now the Menu is viewing. Maybe it has something to do with the desktop environment, since I swapped from Unity to Gnome (?). I will try to fix the exit bugs. Ty for your help. Greetings